# ASP.NET WebApi for SPA without CORS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin

I've been testing out using ASP.NET WebAPI along with AngularJS for a few small in-house company web applications.  I really like the flow of it.  I have a default `HomeController` with a single `Index` method that looks similar to:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent(/* index.html */);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

where I return my first `index.html` page, which resides in my application.  My problem is, to get this to work, I have to enable CORS in the OWIN middleware in my Startup.cs.  I'd really like a way to have WebAPI return my index page without having to enable CORS, and allow all subsequent http requests from angular to work without cross-origin enabled.  Is that feasible, or does that go against the whole concept of WebAPI?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: GET requests from browser don't need CORS... Are you sure you are actually rendering the page via normal GET and not querying it with some AJAX  and than doing some sort of `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're not making a cross domain call you don't need to enable cors.
However keep in mind you have to be on the same domain and even the same port.

To ensure the same domain, just host your webapi inside your web application.

Comment: Adding on what TGH says, you'll want something like mywebsite.com/api to host your API - that'll let your javascript access it. Alternatively, you can change everything to JSONP - you might as well go with CORS if you're going that route

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you incorporate some sort of a reverse proxy on the web server hosting the web site, i.e. all pages and api requests have the same URL prefix? The client then calls the API as though the hosting web app is hosting the API too. The hosting web app has reverse proxy configured and all API requests are then just redirected to the actual API at the server level rather than at the client level. Hope that makes sense.